# can't backup DVD with dvdbackup

Tags: linux, backup, dvd

I have purchased a movie on DVD and can not back it up with dvdbackup. `lsdvd` shows this:

```
me@uboot ~ % lsdvd /dev/sr0                       
*** Zero check failed in src/ifo_read.c:566
    for vmgi_mat->zero_6 = 0x0000001400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 Disc Title: PREDESTINATION
Title: 01, Length: 00:00:26.840 Chapters: 03, Cells: 03, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 02, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 03, Length: 00:01:27.640 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 04, Length: 00:01:23.200 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 05, Length: 00:01:31.920 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 06, Length: 00:01:51.400 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 07, Length: 00:01:58.040 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 08, Length: 00:01:54.000 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 09, Length: 00:02:09.240 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 10, Length: 00:02:14.640 Chapters: 02, Cells: 02, Audio streams: 01, Subpictures: 00
Title: 11, Length: 00:00:04.800 Chapters: 01, Cells: 01, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 12, Length: 00:09:40.800 Chapters: 01, Cells: 01, Audio streams: 00, Subpictures: 00
Title: 13, Length: 00:00:04.800 Chapters: 01, Cells: 01, Audio streams: 00, Subpictures: 00
Title: 14, Length: 01:41:12.000 Chapters: 50, Cells: 50, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 15, Length: 00:00:00.480 Chapters: 01, Cells: 01, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 16, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 14, Cells: 16, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 17, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 16, Cells: 18, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 18, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 19, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 20, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 21, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 22, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 23, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 24, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 15, Cells: 17, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 25, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 21, Cells: 23, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 26, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 21, Cells: 23, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 27, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 28, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 29, Length: 01:27:30.960 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 30, Length: 01:33:43.600 Chapters: 13, Cells: 15, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Title: 31, Length: 01:35:51.760 Chapters: 13, Cells: 23, Audio streams: 04, Subpictures: 02
Longest track: 14
```

When I backup title 14 with `dvdbackup -i /dev/sr0 -T 14 -o ~/Videos`, I only get an unwatchable 103MB VOB file.

Could this be a kind of copy protection, or where could a look for the problem? The DVD itself is watchable with `vlc` or `mpv` video players.

I have also tried to backup the whole DVD, and it led to 23GB + and counting, so I canceled it.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issues with copy protection. The author of this [article](http://richard.esplins.org/siwi/2013/12/27/backup-encrypted-dvds-linux/) also had trouble using dvdbackup, "I also tried dvdbackup, dvd::rip, dvd95, and k9copy. None of them could read my troublesome DVDs"